# Parallelise extraction of bash array elements with awk

Tags: bash, awk

My dummy bash array is:

```
   myArray=(Ann Becky Diana)
```

My dummy file looks like this:

```
   Ann       9  
   Becky     7
   Caroline  8
   Diana     5
```

I want to extract/grep all lines from my dummy file that starts with items from `myArray`, for result like this:

```
   Ann       9  
   Becky     7
   Diana     5
```

I can do this using for loop:

```
  for NAME in "${myArray[@]}"; do
      awk -v NAME="$NAME" '/^NAME/' dummy.file >> output
  done
```

**My question**
How to send bash array to awk and extract wanted info without using loop? Is it possible to operate on whole array?

I hope that it is possible to do something similar to this:

```
   awk -v ARRAY="${myArray[*]}" '/^ARRAY/' dummy.file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -Ff` with `printf` like this:

```
array=(Ann Becky Diana)

grep -Ff <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}") f
Ann       9
Becky     7
Diana     5
```

PS: You **cannot have** `my.array=(Ann Becky Diana)` as `my.array` in an invalid shell variable name due to use of dot in it.

Comment: Ok good, this is indeed the output you expected right from this `grep`?

Comment: Yes this works. Though I would still and `w` to `grep`: `grep -wFf`.

Comment: Yes `-w` will be handy option in this `grep`

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
myarray=(Ann Becky Diana)
awk -v ARR="{myarray[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(ARR,list," ")} {
   for (i=1;i<=length(list);i++)
       if($1 == list[i])
          print $0
}' dummy.txt
```

We pass the `myarray` to awk in `ARR` variable. In `BEGIN`, we split and save into `list` array to be used inside `awk`.